# Insert Date and Time string value into a new DateTime object

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have this:

```
string[] array ={ "04-10-2014", "03:00AM"}
```

I know I can parse the strings and insert them into DateTime object, but i was wondering if there's a quicker way to do this?

Comment: because I am a slow typist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) object or [DataTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx)

Example of doing by Convert

```
var result = Convert.ToDateTime(string.Join(" ", array)).Dump();
```

DateTime.Parse has more option for conversion.
The simple conversion is:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(string.Join(" ", array));
```

If you need to specify culture specific format you would do it

```
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);
var result = DateTime.Parse(string.Join(" ", array), culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Comment: date time format information should be provided while parsing in order to not face the FormatException